# Por que as tags do stackoverflow em português não possuem ícones?

Tags: debate, tags

Se tem algo que tem me despertado a curiosidade ultimamente é que sempre que passo pelo stackoverflow internacional é que vejo ícones nas tags, por exemplo, a tag do android possui o ícone do android, a tag do android studio possui a tag da ide.

Então por que o stackoverflow em português não seguiu essa tendência?

Comment: Pq nenhuma empresa pagou por isso ainda